# Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac {\exp (1/z)}{1-\sin(1/z)}$ around 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

as you can see i would like to expand in a Taylor-Laurent around 0 the function in the title. I can kinda see that it should be an essential singularity, because it should be for ${\exp (1/z)}$ and for $\frac {1}{1-\sin(1/z)}$. However i don't figure out how to expand each term in a Laurent series, to prove that is an essential singularity by seeing that the negative powers are infinite. Is the Laurent series expansion around $0$ even possible? I thought it always was even for essential singularities.

Comment: For $z_k=1/(2\pi k+\pi/2)$ you have $\sin(1/z_k)=1$. Thus each $z_k$ is a singularity of $f$ and since $z_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ the point $0$ is not an isolated singularity. So, there is no Laurent series around $0$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much i didn't realise it was a non isolated singularity. Is it a general case that you can't expand a function as a Laurent series around a non isolated singularity? I mean it kinda makes sense to me because you can't find any subset without encountering a singularity, but i never heard about it, so just asking for confirmation :) .

Comment: btw i want to upvote u but idk how to do it

Comment: Right, you can't expand a function as a Laurent series around a non isolated singularity in a pointed neighborhood of the singularity. Of course you can get Laurent series on each annulus $|z_{k+1}| < |z| < |z_k|$ for each $k$. If this was a homework maybe this was the task.